# Image not Saved in the CoreData from Web API JSON Format?

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swift3

can't save image to core data from web api JSON and **get_details?.logo is in String data type and task.logo is in Binary Data in Core data** can't figure out what's wrong in my code , directly saving image from assets its working but from JSON api its not saving !!

**func bookmarktoCoredata**

```
func bookmarktoCoredata(){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add BookMark", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default){
        (action) in

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchId = ((self.get_details?.schoolid)!)
        let bookmarkFetch: NSFetchRequest<Bookmark> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Bookmark")
        bookmarkFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bookmark_id == %d", fetchId)
        do {
            let fetchedBookmarks = try context.fetch(bookmarkFetch)
            // you should find 1
            if fetchedBookmarks.count == 1 {
                print("same id")
            } else if fetchedBookmarks.count == 0 {
                // There is no Bookmark with this id so create a new one
                let task = Bookmark(context: context)
                // Populate all the properties here and save

                task.bookmark_id = Int16((self.get_details?.schoolid)!)

                task.name = self.get_details?.name
                task.address = self.get_details?.address
                task.district = self.get_details?.district
                task.country = self.get_details?.country
                task.phone = self.get_details?.phone
                task.email = self.get_details?.email
                task.website = self.get_details?.website
                task.institution = self.get_details?.institution_type
                task.establishment = self.get_details?.establishment_date
                task.admission_open = self.get_details?.admission_open_from
                task.admission_end = self.get_details?.admission_open_from
                task.latitude = (self.get_details?.latitude)!
                task.longitude = (self.get_details?.longitude)!
                task.bookmark_type = "school"


                **if let imgdata = ((self.get_details?.logo)){
                task.logo = (UIImage(named: imgdata)) as NSData

                }**




              (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()


                // Populate all the properties here and save
            } else {
                // If you get here you have more than one with the same id. Fix error
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch bookmark: \(error)")
        }


 }
```

> How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Could you give an example of what the string ` get_details?.logo` looks like?

Comment: get_details?.logo its in string data type in model class from JSON api and need to save it in core data in binary data @JonRose

Comment: The way you are using the string you get from the server (ie `UIImage(named: imgdata)` ) it seems like you expect the string to refer to a path in you bundle (ie something like `logo1.png`.  But the way you talk about it makes it seem like it is base64 data.  I asked for an example in order to clarify what the string actually contains.

Comment: its an image url string from web api and i am able to save image directly by giving assets image name and in core data i need to save image in Binary data type ?

Comment: 1) UIImage(name:) will not work for image URL

Comment: 2) why not just save the image URL and download/display the images as needed using something like SDWebImage?

Comment: i tried in SDWebImage too but cannot save the url and download/display can you help me ??

Comment: what does the string `self.get_details?.logo` look most similar to:  1) "http://images.myserer/images/bsedkslkdsl.png " 2) 'logo4.png` or 3) "YXNkZmFzZGZhc2RmYXNkZmFmZHNhc...=="

Comment: it looks like "www.myeducationhunt.com\/UaWBB8gcwiCVnbz27o2i.jpg" these type and similar to 1

Comment: First just save the string - `task.logo = self.get_details?.logo`.  Then install sdWebimage and use something like: `imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: task.logo), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))` to display the image.  SDWebimage will also manage the cache for you and save it in the tmp directory (which is better for many reason than saving it in core data).  If you have problems with that then post a new question.

Comment: It works great and so easy way i was just trying to save direct image , Thanks a lot for helping me and how will i give this question correct can please write the code so i could thick this ?? And Thanks  a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is a bad practice to save image data into core data.  Managing large amount of data like that is not was a database is designed to do.  A file system is much better choice.  You could set core-data to store an attribute as separate file, but in this case there is a much better solution.

Just save the url as is into core-data:  `task.logo = self.get_details?.logo` and only download it when you need to display it.  I recommend using `SDWebimage`.  When you need to display it load the url into the imageView like `imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: task.logo), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))`.

This has many advantages: 1) it will only load the image if it is needed   2) it will cache the images that it download in the tmp directory of the app - (so the OS can delete it if it needs to). 3) it also deals with the download time in a more transparent way - you can either set a placeholder image, or if you want more control you can use the more complex `SDWebimage` methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir and now got this knowledge from you thanks it will help me in future too.. Happy coding.. !!!